# how to inject $attrs into a controller through $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have a mini app with a controller that looks like that:

```
app.controller("MyController", [ '$scope', '$attrs', 'ServiceA', 'ServiceB', function($scope, $attrs, svc1, svc2) {
  ...
}])
```

When I tried to add angular-routing to my app, I added the following route.js file:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
            controller: 'MyController',
            controllerAs: 'appCtrl',
            resolve: {
                attrs: $attrs
            }
        })
    }
]);
```

It seems that I can't inject `$attrs` like before. I've tried playing with `resolve` inside `when()` but it didn't seem to help.

I must say it looks a bit weird to inject `$attrs` into the controller anyway, and since that's my first app I think I'm doing something wrong here.. I need `$attrs` to read a data attribute from the div and initialize some array according to it. Any ideas to how I should do it or why I couldn't do it with my approach? (which worked without the `routes`)

Thanks!

Comment: what is $attrs do? $routeParams, does not work for that?

Comment: It's difficult to work out what you want to do. Have you looked at the example at the bottom of this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example?